# onLayout calculate width by left and right (same size)

Tags: java, android, kotlin

What is the correct approach to calculate the width given by the parameters of the [onLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#onLayout(boolean,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) function:

**Setup**

```
override fun onLayout(changed: Boolean, left: Int, top: Int, right: Int, bottom: Int) {
  super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom)
  val width = ...
}
```

**Approach 1:**

```
val width = right - left
```

**Approach 2:**

```
val width = right - left + 1
```

**How does this `+1` come into my mind?**

Depending on whether the `right` coordinate is written from the right or left edge of the coordinate the width can either be `0px` or `1px`. If (what I assume) `left` is written and calculated from the left edge and `right` is written and calculated from the right edge of the coordinate, then in between both points there is `1px` (the pixel at position 10). Vice versa if both points are written and calculated from the left edge, the width is simply `0px`.

I hope I could communicate my thoughts. Thanks in advance for your help.

If `left=10` and `right=10` depending on from where the `right` coordinate is written there can be `1px` between both points. If `right` is written from the `right-edge` there should be exactly `1px` between those two points. If `right` is written from the `left-edge` (what I expect from the `left` point as well) the space between should be `0px`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`right - left` is the way to go. A view can have a width of `0px`. I don't think it is necessary to use `right - left + 1` since that will always give the wrong result by 1px.

However, since the `onLayout` function is called multiple times, the first value that is calculated might change in the future, I've seen it happening even in the first layout drawing pass because some layouts measure the views more than once. In the end, I'd say you should use `getWidth()` or `getHeight()` after `onGlobalLayout()` is called which you can add with `getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(OnGlobalLayoutListener)`.